# Before 'auto' what?

Tags: c++, auto

I am using a C++ book which was written under the new standard of C++11 (C++ primer) and I see that he uses a LOT of times the `auto`. Saying all the time that it is really hard to explain the exact type so we use it. My question is, what programmers where using before `auto`? For example in simple loops with `begin()` and `end()` functions he uses auto to determine the variable's type.

Comment: They wrote down the actual type name. What do you expect?

Comment: People just used the types along with an iterator based loop.

Comment: We prefer to forget about those troubled times :) Writing the types in full is indeed quite painful. I remember using `typedef` a lot to lighten expressions a bit. Things like `boost::foreach` helped somewhat, but only slightly.

Comment: There was `BOOST_AUTO`. Not as powerful, but still useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They used the explicit type. You can think of `auto` as an universal alias. Compare the following:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
for(std::vector<int>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
    //doStuff

std::vector<int> vec;
for(auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
    //doStuff
```

Comment: Thank You :) Really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Life before `auto` everything had to be explicitly declared.

Comment: Life was hard back then. :)

Answer (score 2):

Before `auto` we used `typedef`s to have shorter aliases for long types. Currently we use `using` instead of `typedef` to have more context-related alias for a type but we have lot less need for shorter aliases.